# How to check if a process with Command line argument is running using python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I would like to check if a script is running with a specific command line argument within a python script.

For example I would like to check if:

```
main.py testarg
```

Is running. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you checking this from another script, or from `main.py`?

Comment: I think my explanation was a little poor. Within main.py I would like to check at runtime if another main.py with the same command line argument is already running. If there is another instance of "main.py testarg" then exit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To search through the currently running processes, you should use a library such as [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) to ensure maximum platform compatibility.

```
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    cmdline = process.cmdline()
    if "main.py" in cmdline and "testarg" in cmdline:
        # do something
```

---

If instead you are looking to search through the arguments of the current process you can use the `sys.argv` list:

```
import sys

if "testarg" in sys.argv:
    # do something
```

For more complex argument parsing, it is recommended to use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: I think perhaps they mean "can I tell if that process is running", not "can I tell if this process was called with this arg", something like `ps x | grep "main.py testarg"`

Comment: Ah yes, I guess that could be true.

Comment: It should be cmdline = process.cmdline() instead of cmdline = process.cmdline

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem asked. @Bakuriu's post is the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library.

```
import psutil

process_is_running = False

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.cmdline == what_you_want:
        process_is_running = True
```

This will work on almost any OS and with python 2.4 up to 3.3.

Comment: +1 Just a minor point, in python3 `process.cmdline` is a method. So above should be changed to `if process.cmdline() == what_you_want:` (not sure about `python2`)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my take of it:**

```
import psutil

L=[(p.name(),p.cmdline()[1]) for p in psutil.process_iter() if p.name().startswith('py')]
```

Now if you print this list L out:

```
('py.exe', 'programs\\pad29.py')
('python.exe', 'programs\\pad29.py')
('python.exe', '-u')
....
('python.exe', 'programs\\test_signal.py')
```

The list contains the command line parameters of every running process whose name starts with 'py'. That would include **python.exe** and **py.exe**. The condition is necessary otherwise you may run into some ***AccessDenied error*** if you try to poke on every running Windows process, like some **smss.exe**.
Once you have this list, finding out what you want is a no brainer:

```
t=['what_you_want' == m[1] for m in L]
answer=True in t
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me when I wanted to match specific process with specific arguments :

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if ( proc.name().startswith('ruby')) and ("service-buffer.rb" in proc.cmdline()[1]) :
        print("match", proc.cmdline()[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:   # else get PermissionError
        pid     = p.pid
        cmdline = p.cmdline()
        print(pid)
        for cmd in cmdline:
            print(cmd)
        print()
    except:
        pass
```