# How can I find the Command Line of a Process with Python?

Tags: python, command-line

I tried to get the Command Line of a running Process with Python.
I managed to do it with Powershell but I need to get it with Python which is my Problem.

Working Powershell Code:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'process.exe'" | select CommandLine
```

I tried everything I found but still can't do it...
It would be very nice if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721781/18505766</strike>

```py
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    cmdline = process.cmdline
    if "main.py" in cmdline and "testarg" in cmdline:
        # do something
```

*EDIT: Sorry, actually this is a bit different.*
But if you're on Windows, you can try the following:

```py
import wmi
w=wmi.WMI()
name = "cmd.exe"
for process in w.Win32_Process():
    if process.Name == name:
        tmp1 = process.Commandline
        tmp2 = tmp1.split(' ', 1)
        args = tmp2[1]
        break
print(args)
```

EDIT2: improved code. Important: only the first process' arguments found are stored in var 'args'!

Comment: Just change "main.py" to the process name you want

Comment: and where do I have to put my Process in? Sorry im not the best at this...

Comment: Replace "cmd.exe" with the name of your process.